# Poor man's "namespaces"

Tags: macros, external-files

I have searched for "namespaces", but all of these posts seem to ask for something way more advanced.

The problem I encounter can be solved by renaming everything, but that does not seem "right".
There are bunch of commands in my document such as `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` for vectors in the physics part. However, I would like to include papers in my final thesis where sometimes the same command is used with a different definition (different field). Hence, the files would compile on themselves, but if I include them in my larger document (such that they get page numbers and included in the TOC) this will give collisions.

So my question is: Is it possible to "rewrite" a prefix in a command on a per-file basis? That would be, I define `\newcommand{\jonas@vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` and in my particular document `jonas.tex` I would rewrite all commands `\jonas@vec` to the one with the part without `\jonas@`. This would allow me to use the same syntax, but have a different definition.

Comment: Redefinitions can be scoped within a `\begingroup...\endgroup`, so it is just a matter of figuring out a system to define where the group begins and ends.  I usually limit the redefinitions to be within environments so only that environment sees this new definition, but outside of this specific environment the usual meaning is applied.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks! So perhaps the filehook (I believe) package will help me there?

Comment: Could you make some more examples of redefined commands?

Comment: I will come back to this question asap, have to write the paper now, not mess with getting the .tex better :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's an attempt at an answer. If it's not helpful in your particular case, maybe we can rework it together.

The key to making redefinitions *local* to a particular document is *grouping* the respective code, as already remarked in the comments.

The main question is how you're including the individual documents. Assuming you're using the `combine` class, the main document might look something like this:

```
\documentclass[report]{combine}

\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=4.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{combinet}

\begin{document}

\title{My title Main}

\author{Myself}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\begin{papers}

  \import{testinclude1}

  \import{testinclude2}

\end{papers}

\chapter{Main Chapter}

$\vec{A}$

\end{document}
```

Assume further that `testinclude1.tex` looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\title{My title One}

\author{Myself}

\maketitle

foo bar

$\vec{A}$

\end{document}
```

Then the redefinition of `\vec` will "spill" into `testinclude2.tex`, but not out of the `papers` environment (as it is local to environments).

If you enclose the `\import` calls in `{}` (which also form a group), then the redefinition of `\vec` will be completely local to `testinclude1.tex`:

```
{\import{testinclude1}}

{\import{testinclude2}}
```

Not knowing the `combine` class in detail, I don't expect any averse effects from the grouping as things like table of contents entries work through the `.aux` file.

[image: example output]

Does this help you in any way?

Comment: This is just perfect! :-). I was unaware of the existence of the 'combine' class.